# how to add the dynamically added tr data at the top row of the table in pug?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

how to add the dynamically added tr data at the top row of the table in pug?
here it's adding at the bottom

the code I have written...
any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance

```
<tbody>

        if records.length 

            each record, index in records

                - const sl = index + 1, id = record._id.toString();

                    tr(class="data record" data-id= id)

                        th(scope="row") #{sl}
                        td(class="name") #{record.studentName}
                        td(class="subject") #{record.subject}
                        td(class="theory") #{record.theory}
                        td(class="practical") #{record.practical}
                        td(class="total") #{record.total}
                        td
                            a(href="#" class="editBttn") Edit
                        td
                            a(href="#" class="delBttn") Delete

        else

            tr(class="data no-record")

                td(colspan="8") No records are available...


    </tbody>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the dynamically added tr data"?

Comment: dynamically added table row data

Comment: printing the data from form's input

Comment: Consider reversing the order of the items in the `record` list/array.